# Separate this in different rows

Tags: tex-core

```
To calculate market value, can use \textbf{calculator}:
[2nd][FV]: Clean previous data 
[FV] = Face Value 
[N] = Periods in which coupon payments happen 
[I/Y] = Market interest rate (YTM)
```

That's how it should be.

This is what is happening:
[image]

When I put a \ \ after each line, it throws an error. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It is built into LaTeX that if the next character after a double backslash is an open bracket, the bracketed expression is expected to be a dimension, used to adjust the spacing after the line break.  If you precede the bracketed expression with `\relax` that check will be suppressed, and the expression will be typeset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown because `\\` takes an optional argument and the `[FV]` in the next line is interpreted as such, but the optional argument to `\\` should be a valid TeX dimension, which `FV` obviously isn't. You can put a `\relax` after `\\` to make it stop looking for an optional argument:

```
To calculate market value, can use \textbf{calculator}:\\\relax
[2nd][FV]: Clean previous data\\\relax
[FV] = Face Value\\\relax
[N] = Periods in which coupon payments happen\\\relax
[I/Y] = Market interest rate (YTM) % as noted by egreg, don't put \\\relax on the last line of the paragraph
```

But perhaps it's a better idea to use an environment like `description` for this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
To calculate market value, can use \textbf{calculator}:
\begin{description}[nosep, font=\ttfamily]
  \item[{[2nd][FV]}] Clean previous data 
  \item[{[FV]}] Face Value
  \item[{[N]}] Periods in which coupon payments happen 
  \item[{[I/Y]}] Market interest rate (YTM) 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This way you can quickly change the style to your liking with using the `enumitem` setup.

Comment: Remove the last ``\\\relax`` If followed by a blank line it would just generate an annoying warning.

Comment: @egreg you're right.